# How and where can I change the animation of closing a NSPanel when I click the red close button?

Tags: objective-c, animated, nspanel

I present a NSPanel in a NSWindowController. When I press the little red button of the titlebar of the NSPanel I would like to change the way it disappears with a different animation. How do I do that? Is there something like -(void)closeButtonPressed that I can change. Because the -(void)close of the NSWindow is not working like I want it. When I present it I do it like this:

```
[self.imagePanelController.previewPanel setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(self.window.frame.origin.x + self.window.frame.size.width/4 , self.window.frame.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height/4, self.ciImage.extent.size.width, self.ciImage.extent.size.height)) display:YES animate:YES];
```

I would like to set a new frame again and animate that, when pressing the panel close button. Any ideas?

Comment: Short of rendering the thing into a layer and animating it, Windows have an [animation behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setAnimationBehavior:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself, and it works for me, I don't know if that is the best solution, but does exactly what I needed. So I just post this, if someone is looking for something similar.

I am getting the closeButton of the NSPanel and perform than a action on it to close the panel exactly in the way it animated to open the panel.

```
NSButton *closeButton = [self.imagePanelController.previewPanel standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton];
    [closeButton setTarget:self];
    [closeButton setAction:@selector(closePanel)];

- (void)closePanel
{

    int calcX = self.window.frame.size.width - self.bounds.size.width;
    int x = self.window.frame.origin.x + calcX;
    int y = self.window.frame.origin.y;
    int width = self.bounds.size.width;
    int height = self.bounds.size.height;

    [self.imagePanelController.previewPanel setFrame:NSRectFromCGRect(CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)) display:YES animate:YES];
    [self.imagePanelController.previewPanel close];

}
```